# vue-resource get request not working on Laravel 5.3

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vue-resource

It's a fresh Laravel 5.3 installation on MAMP.

I'm trying to fetch data from a json API endpoint with vue-resource's get request.
But it's returning an empty array.

Here's my app.js
I haven't used any components here.

```
Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('#token').getAttribute('content');

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#main',
    data: { 
        searchString: "",
        articles: []
    },
    ready: function() {
        this.fetchData();
    },
    methods: {
        fetchData: function () {
            this.$http.get('http://localhost:8888/pos/public/api/items',     function(articles) {
                this.$set('filteredArticles', articles);
            });
        }
    },
    computed: {
    // A computed property that holds only those articles that match the searchString.
    filteredArticles: function () {
        var articles_array = this.articles,
            searchString = this.searchString;

        if(!searchString){
            return articles_array;
        }

        searchString = searchString.trim().toLowerCase();

        articles_array = articles_array.filter(function(item){
            if(item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1){
                return item;
            }
        })

        // Return an array with the filtered data.
        return articles_array;;
    }
}
});
```

Here's the html form the view:

```
<div class="col-md-3" id="main">
    <label for="Search">Search Item</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" v-model="searchString" placeholder="Search here" />
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="article in filteredArticles">@{{ article.id }}</li>      
        </ul>

</div>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here, firstly as Belmin said, `laravel` comes with `Vue 2` and `ready()` is a `Vue 1` lifecycle hook, instead you need to use the [created lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created)

Secondly, the correct syntax for `Vue-router` is:

```
  // GET /someUrl
  this.$http.get('/someUrl').then((response) => {
    // success callback
  }, (response) => {
    // error callback
  });
```

The second parameter is for passing options, not for the `success` callback:

```
Vue.http.get('/someUrl', [options]).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

You can find more about this on the [Vue-Router Github page](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/master/docs/http.md)

So you should end up with this:

```
//...
  created: function() {
    this.fetchData();
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData: function() {
      this.$http.get('http://localhost:8888/pos/public/api/items').then(function(articles) {
        this.filteredArticles = articles
      });
    }
  },
//...
```

Here's a JSFiddle to show the correct syntax: https://jsfiddle.net/mLjajttz/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. By the way in my Laravel 5.3 it's Vue 1.0.28 I don't know why. Should I try Vue 2.1.8 and try above procedure?

Comment: That's strange, `Laravel` started shipping with `Vue 2` a couple of months back, but yes, you should update to `Vue 2`, it's a vast improvement on `Vue 1`, and make sure you have the most up to date version of `vue-router` also.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Laravel comes out with VueJS 2.0 version.In Vue2 `ready()` lifecycle hook is deprecated so you have to use `created()` or `mounted()` depending on your use case.